# JQuery Keydown, Keypress, Keycode, etc

Tags: jquery, html, key, keypress, keydown

I'm looking for some help on why the shift key in the current arrangement doesn't fire when the key is pressed. In the code below, every single key/character works as expected, with exception of the shift key. I'd love any help that anyone can give me. I've changed the keydown even to keypress, keyup; still, nothing.

Included is the actual code, and a Fiddle where everything is operational.

http://jsfiddle.net/yKCSw/

Thanks in advance!

```
<pre>
<div id="keyboard">
    <row class="one">
        <key class="single esc">esc</key>
        <key class="single f1">F1</key>
        <key class="single f2">f2</key>
        <key class="single f3">f3</key>
        <key class="single f4">f4</key>
        <key class="single f5">f5</key>
        <key class="single f6">f6</key>
        <key class="single f7">f7</key>
        <key class="single f8">f8</key>
        <key class="single f9">f9</key>
        <key class="single f10">f10</key>
        <key class="single f11">f11</key>
        <key class="single f12">f12</key>
        <key class="single f13">F13</key>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    <row class="two">
        <key class="double til">~<span>`</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 1">!<span>1</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 2">@<span>2</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 3">#<span>3</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 4">$<span>4</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 5">%<span>5</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 6">^<span>6</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 7">&<span>7</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 8">*<span>8</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 9">(<span>9</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double 0">)<span>0</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double hyp">_<span>-</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double equ">+<span>=</span>

        </key>
        <key class="single delete right">Delete</key>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    <row class="three">
        <key class="tab left">Tab</key>
        <key class="single q">q</key>
        <key class="single w">w</key>
        <key class="single e">e</key>
        <key class="single r">r</key>
        <key class="single t">t</key>
        <key class="single y">y</key>
        <key class="single u">u</key>
        <key class="single i">i</key>
        <key class="single o">o</key>
        <key class="single p">p</key>
        <key class="double lbrack">{<span>[</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double rbrack">}<span>]</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double bs">|<span>\</span>

        </key>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    <row class="four">
        <key class="single caps left">Caps lock</key>
        <key class="single a">a</key>
        <key class="single s">s</key>
        <key class="single d">d</key>
        <key class="single f">f</key>
        <key class="single g">g</key>
        <key class="single h">h</key>
        <key class="single j">j</key>
        <key class="single k">k</key>
        <key class="single l">l</key>
        <key class="double col">:<span>;</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double apos">"<span>'</span>

        </key>
        <key class="single return right double">Enter<span>return</span>

        </key>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
    <row class="five">
        <key class="single shft left">Shift</key>
        <key class="single z">z</key>
        <key class="single x">x</key>
        <key class="single c">c</key>
        <key class="single v">v</key>
        <key class="single b">b</key>
        <key class="single n">n</key>
        <key class="single m">m</key>
        <key class="double comm">
            <<span>,</span>
        </key>
        <key class="double great">><span>.</span>

        </key>
        <key class="double quest">?<span>/</span>

        </key>
        <key class="single shft right">Shift</key>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </row>
</div>
</pre>
```

JQuery -

```
$('body').on('keydown', function (e) {

    var p = e.which;

    if (p === 27) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.esc').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 112) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f1').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 113) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f2').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 114) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f3').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 115) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f4').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 116) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f5').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 117) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f6').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 118) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f7').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 119) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f8').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 120) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f9').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 121) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f10').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 122) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f11').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 123) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f12').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 192) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.til').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 49) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.1').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 50) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.2').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 51) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.3').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 52) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.4').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 53) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.5').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 54) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.6').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 55) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.7').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 56) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.8').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 57) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.9').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 48) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.0').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 189) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hyp').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 187) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.equ').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.delete').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tab').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 81) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.q').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 87) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.w').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 69) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.e').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 82) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.r').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 84) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.t').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 89) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.y').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 85) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.u').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 73) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.i').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 79) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.o').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 80) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.p').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 219) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.lbrack').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 221) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.rbrack').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 220) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.bs').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 20) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.caps').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 65) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.a').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 83) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.s').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 68) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.d').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 70) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.f').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 71) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.g').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 72) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.h').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 74) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.j').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 75) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.k').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 76) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.l').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 186) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.col').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 222) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.apos').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.return').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 16) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.shft').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 90) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.z').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 88) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.x').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 67) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.c').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 86) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.v').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 66) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.b').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 78) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.n').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 77) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.m').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 188) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.comm').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 190) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.great').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 191) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.quest').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    } else if (p === 16) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.shft').addClass('active');
    } else if (p === 220) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.bs').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: Please learn to post only relevant parts of your code...

Comment: Please learn to post only relevant answers to people's inquiries.

Comment: @jayjo don't take it so rude, posting only relevant code speed up greatly to spot bugs

Comment: @jayjo Arrogance is not really a good trait when you are asking for free help. I was trying to help, the FAQ and common sense says just what I advised.

Comment: Right, but I guess in this case I wasn't aware as to what wasn't relevant code. I'm still not actually. What should I not have posted?

Comment: And I wasn't trying to be arrogant. Helpful critique shows where a problem lies, not just that there's a problem. It would have been nice knowing "what" code wasn't relevant in this instance.

Comment: @jayjo Most of your JS code is the repetition of the same code (which in itself begs for refactoring, but that's a different thing), the first if and the last two ifs would have been just enough, with a `...` between maybe. Same with the markup. My critique was helpful even if I did not tell you the exact steps to solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your explanation. I'm pretty new (if it's not obvious) to dev work. I'll certainly look into cleaning this up, and I'll try to eliminate unnecessary code in future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were removing class after added it: {there are two .shift buttons}

```
$('.shft').addClass('active').siblings().not('.shft').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: There it is... jeeeeeez, thanks Roasted. That makes complete sense, and I feel like an idiot. Haha. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the shift key was pressed using `e.shiftKey`.
I've added some code on your jsfiddle:

```
if(e.shiftKey){
  $('key').removeClass('active');
  $('.shft').addClass('active');
}
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKCSw/2/)